# Android native crash debug symbols

Tags: android, android-ndk, native

I am new to debugging Android at native level. So, I need some help regarding that. Suppose I am having an app using some native library. Sometimes, the app is getting crashed at native code and I have the logcat and tombstone for the crash. But as I can see at other places, I need debug symbols to convert the backtrace/memory locations to exact line of faulty code . Where can I find these debug symbols . I have ROM for the device, device itself, code of .so file. But the crash occurs randomly, so it is not possible to apply debug points at java level. So, can anybody guide me where can I find these debug symbols (inside ROM/ phone)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debug symbols are placed in `.so` files that can be found at `obj/local/<target_arch>/` dir. Note that these `.so` is not the same as ones that are packed into `apk`. The former are full binaries that have both machine code and debug info, and the latter are stripped binaries that are prepared for deployment, and contain only machine code.

Also NDK has nice utility called `ndk-stack` that helps to convert raw crash trace to more useful : representation. See [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-stack.html) for details.